# VBA to populate names

Tags: vba

I need help to create one VBA for below issue -
column C should be updated based on column A and B values.
in below example if column A=Unit1 and column B=IND then Person 1 and so on.. it should loop till end.
Thank you in adv. please refer picture for sample data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9Oga.png)

Comment: Your pattern in the picture doesn't make sense for what you're asking. How does it change to person 3 on row 11?

Comment: I understand that you are new to SO (Welcome!). But your question is really unclear. Look at your picture, read the text of your question and try to tell why Person3 suddenly appeared for Unit5

Comment: Thank you John :- ) column C is populated by VBA. column C is based on Column A and Column B. Unit 5 and Loc = OTR is processed by Person 3

Comment: Yes but why is unit 1-4 of OTR "Person2" and unit5 of OTR is person 3. How is the code supposed to know when to go to the next person?

Comment: There will be only 3 person. Unit 1-5 and Loc IND processed by person 1, Unit 1-4 and Loc OTR processed by person 2, only unit 5 loc OTR processed by person 3.  So VBA should populate 3rd column as person 1 or 2 or 3 based on unit and loc

Comment: Ok well that's easy enough. You should have all this information in your original question. Questions like this often get closed because there isn't enough information  or clarity to go off.

Comment: In file only 2 columns are there.. 3rd column is based on combination of 1st and 2nd columns..

Comment: Apologize for the same . Will maintain clarity going forward

Comment: And you don't want a formula? You want VBA as a normal formula can do this easily as well.

Comment: i have formula.. but i need it in VBA. presently i am using formula then paste it as values..

Comment: Whats your current formula? Is it something like this: `=IF(B1="IND","Person1",IF(AND(B1="OTR",A1="Unit 5"),"Person3","Person2"))` ? As basically you have said that if it's `IND` Then it's Person1, if it's `OTR` AND `Unit 5` Then it's Person3, otherwise it's person2. Am I correct?

Comment: Perfect Simon. i have same formula.. need it in VBA so it updates till last record (loop)

Comment: I've added my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Just change the sheet name since I don't know what you're working with.

```
Sub AddPerson()

Dim i As Long, ws As Worksheet, lRow As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your sheet name

lRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With ws
.Range("C2:C" & lRow + 1).ClearContents
For i = 2 To lRow
        If .Range("B" & i) = "IND" Then
            .Range("C" & i) = "Person1"
        ElseIf .Range("A" & i) = "Unit5" And .Range("B" & i) = "OTR" Then
            .Range("C" & i) = "Person3"
        Else
            .Range("C" & i) = "Person2"
        End If
Next i
End With

End Sub
```